# sqlite3 database error .. i really get tired :(

Tags: sqlite, scrapy

i really need help to finish this task since it's related to my research and I’m new to python and scrapy .

***the task is to select all input field (type=text or password or file ) and store it's (id) in back-end DB , besides the page link where this input belongs ***

my code to select input fields

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log('%s' % response.url)

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item=IsaItem()
    item['response_fld']=response.url

    item['text_input']=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'text' )]/@id ").extract()
    item['pass_input']=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()
    item['file_input']=hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'file')]/@id").extract()

    return item
```

Database pipeline code :

```
class SQLiteStorePipeline(object):


def __init__(self):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('./project.db')
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()


def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)" , (item['text_input'][0] ), )
    self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)" , (item['pass_input'][0]  ,))
    self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)" ,(item['file_input'][0] ,  ))

    self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(?)", (item['response_fld'][0], ))

    self.conn.commit()
    return item
```

but i still get error like this

```
self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)" , (item['text_input'][0] ), )
exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
```

***or database store only first letter !!***

```
Database links table 
 ╔════════════════╗
 ║      links     ║ 
 ╠════════════════╣
 ║  id  │input    ║ 
 ╟──────┼─────────╢
 ║    1 │     t   ║ 
 ╟──────┼─────────╢
 ║    2 │     t   ║ 
 ╚══════╧═════════╝
Note it should "tbPassword" or "tbUsername"
```

ouput fron json file

```
{"pass_input": ["tbPassword"], "file_input": [], "response_fld":     "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/Signup.aspx", "text_input": ["tbUsername"]}
{"pass_input": [], "file_input": [], "response_fld": "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/default.aspx", "text_input": []}
{"pass_input": ["tbPassword"], "file_input": [], "response_fld": "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/login.aspx", "text_input": ["tbUsername"]}
{"pass_input": [], "file_input": [], "response_fld": "http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/Comments.aspx?id=0", "text_input": []}
```

Comment: i'm stuck in this point since `two or three`days :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `IndexError` because you try to get the first item in the list, which sometimes is empty.

I would do it like this.

The spider:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log('%s' % response.url)

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = IsaItem()
    item['response_fld'] = response.url

    res = hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'text' )]/@id ").extract()
    item['text_input'] = res[0] if res else None # None is default value in case no field found

    res = hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()
    item['pass_input'] = res[0] if res else None # None is default value in case no field found

    res = hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'file')]/@id").extract()
    item['file_input'] = res[0] if res else None # None is default value in case no field found

    return item
```

The pipeline:

```
class SQLiteStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('./project.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)", (item['text_input'],))
        self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)", (item['pass_input'],))
        self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)", (item['file_input'],))

        self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(?)", (item['response_fld'],))

        self.conn.commit()
        return item
```

Comment: thanks a lot , it works but still have a plroblem which  , it gave me  null values in database , which i  don't want  ... also the same problem with links

  `the task is to select all input field (type=text or password or file ) and store it's (id) in back-end DB , besides the page link where this input belongs `

Comment: It puts null values, because of None in `item['text_input'] = res[0] if res else None`. As for your second question, it's not related to this one. Your `inputs` table should have foreign key for `links` table, and you have to fill it. You better make another question with `sql` tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know anything about this technology, but here's my guess:

Try 
`insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)" , (item['text_input'] )`
 instead of 
`insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)" , (item['text_input'][0] )`.

As for the 'list index out of range' error, it seems like your item is empty, something you should check for.